# veewee: build gets stuck during installation of libssl on debian 7.4

Tags: vagrant, preseed

I'm new to vagrant and veewee. I'm trying to build a debian 7.4 image but after running the build

```
veewee vbox build 'debian-7.4'
```

the process gets stuck on the installation of libssl because it requires the user input to restart some services (ssh ntp exim4)

[image: debian libssl]

Unfortunately this is shown inside the terminal and I couldn't find any way to hit "ok" and then, of course, I get this message.

```
SIGNAL: 3                                                                       
Ssh timeout 10000 sec has been reached.
```

Of course I can work around this by continuing the installation by hand through the virtualbox GUI but this should not happen in unattended installation.

How can I force the installation process to restart the services without waiting for the user input?

Comment: Does this software use a `preseed` file under the hood that you can manipulate?

Comment: I suppose and that's what I'm trying to figure out. veewee has "definitions" but I can't understand where/what I should modify to disable interaction

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/customize.md), the tree structure shows a preseed file.

Comment: thank you! unfortunately I checked my definition.rb and I have already 'fb=false ', 'debconf/frontend=noninteractive '

Comment: also in the base.sh I can see 'apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev'. With the '-y' it should run non-interactively. I don't get what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pactrick gave the following answer which solved the exact same issue over on Unix & Linux exchange[1]:

"Set the environment variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive.

For example:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y libssl
```

This will make apt-get select the default options."

[1]https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146283/how-to-prevent-prompt-that-ask-to-restart-services-when-installing-libpq-dev

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate at the `preseed` level, read about `debconf-set-selections`.

Something like this should do:

```
libssl1.0.0:amd64 libssl1.0.0/restart-services string ssh ntp exim4
```